# Canvas circles and line

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, mouseevent

http://jsfiddle.net/cs5Sg/

As you can see, I'm trying to make two circles and one line. When u click on the first cirle u can modify the line position. 
I have 2 questions:

1. How to remove the second line? (The second line swhow up only when I add the second circle.)
2. How to stop the "animation" after `mouseup` event?

Comment: Fixed the stop animation part.Take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/cs5Sg/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only begin one path, hence the line between the two circles, and `start` will always be true in that `if` statement - you should put that inside the `mousemove` listener, and only attach it once.

This creates an arc:

```
context.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
```

And then, this creates an arc on the same path, so there'll be a line from the last one's end to this one's start:

```
context.arc(x1,y1,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
```

Instead, just put them in separate paths:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x1,y1,radius,0,2*Math.PI);

context.moveTo(x,y);
context.lineTo(x1,y1);
context.stroke();
```

[Here's the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/cs5Sg/6/)

Comment: Sorry for the double post @minitech . Didn't observe that you had posted an answer!

Comment: @harsha: Judging by the version number, you did it first :-)